# Why kafka broker didn't filter aborted transactions instead send them to consumers and let consuemers do the filtering?

Tags: apache-kafka

From [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging)， `Note also the addition of the field for aborted transactions. This is used by the consumer in READ_COMMITTED mode to know where aborted transactions begin. This allows the consumer to discard the aborted transaction data without buffering until the associated marker is read.` But why didn't broker just filter all the aborted record or return them as empty record to save the bandwidth and works of consumer developer?

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

1. the broker using zero copy (send file),so broker can't filter aborted transactions message
2. assume aborted  transactions message is very less

Comment: Maybe you are right, but a more certain answer is welcome.